# Rails - Pointing form to controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes

I have a simple controller "Users" which has a show action (for each user). Now, I want to have a textbox on the home page which allows to search for a specific user by username.

So on show action, I accept a username param and I respond with the user object. I've seen form_for() but it seems I need an instance of @user which I don't quite understand, since I am only just retrieving on the next request. I've seen tutorials but they seem to have it under index controller action but I really want it to point to users#show so it will use the assets, template, url path, etc.

So I want a form that would just perform a get request with /users/. Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need instance if you use `form_tag`. You can read more about `form_tag` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

**Example:**

```
<%= form_tag("/search", method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :user %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The html snippet from @Mihail well help you but the example given will require you to create a custom route for the search action.

Add in your routes:

`GET '/search', to: 'users#show'`

Then in your users show action attempt to look up the user by calling:

`@user = User.find_by(id: params[:user])`

Be sure to not use `User.find`, because you will get an error when the user doesn't exist. The last thing you'll need to do is make sure your users/show template is able to handle the case when @user is nil, or instead render some sort of custom user_not_found page instead of the users/show if @user is nil.

Comment: hmm..doing this appends this to my endpoint, ?utf8=✓&search=username&commit=Go, would it be possible to make it so it would point to /users/<username> instead (already existing because I already show a list of users) and it would be better if it would reuse the same controller action

Answer (score 0):

You can use [form_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) instead of `form_for`. Also, all the form helpers have their _tag equivalents. I.e. `select_tag` instead of `f.select` and so on. And don't forget the case when user could not be found, You have to deal with it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add in what I did.

As advised, I've added a route for /search on config/routes.rb.

```
get '/search', to: 'users#search'
```

Then on UsersController, I've added a redirect on search action.

```
  def search
    @username = params[:search]
    redirect_to "#{users_path}/#{@username}"
  end
```

This would now allow me to reuse whatever I have under users#show (templates, url and everything). From what I understand, this will return a 301/302 that would cause another HTTP request so this is not at all optimal. It would probably be cleaner to just share functionality between show and search.